# MongoDB allowDiskUse in sharded cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB 3.2 in a Ruby on Rails application with Mongoid 5 (and the MongoDB Ruby driver).  The MongoDB instance is configured in a development sharded cluster (1 config server, 3 shard servers) running on a single VM.

I was receiving the following error from my application:

```
{ $err: "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", code: 16945 }
```

To address this, I modified the code to provide the allowDiskUse:true option.  However, when that was enabled, I then receive the error:

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: unknown m/r field for sharding: allowDiskUse ()
```

I did not see anything specifically mentioned from MongoDB that allowDiskUse would be restricted in a sharded environment (referencing [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/sharded-cluster-requirements/)).

It was unclear why this limitation is in place (I am assuming there is a reason), or if any workarounds are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being my misunderstanding and error.  As expected, reading the error message and paying attention to details was the key. The original error message was coming from an aggregate command.  In my first attempt, I was very blindly applying the "allowDiskUse" option to all of the MongoDB commands my application was using.  I ended up adding it to mapreduce commands, which does not want the allowDiskUse option.  What threw me was this "worked" fine in a non-sharded environment, but that was more the fluke.

By applying "allowDiskUse" to just the aggregate commands, everything is working fine both in a single server and sharded setup.